# NodeJS + Request Intercept Outgoing Requests

Tags: node.js, request

I am currently using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to make calls to an external service provider for some of my REST API endpoints. I have a consumer key and secret that I can use to get a token which I then attach to every request.

Instead of chaining two operation (getting/refreshing) the token and then requesting (I'm using a promise-based version of request) (see code below). I would like to add a global interceptor that would intercept every outgoing request, fetch or refresh the token and then attach it to the request.

```
getToken().
   then(function (token) {
        return request({
              url: url,
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        });
   })
   .then(function (data) { do things here})
```

any idea on how it can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I intercept all node request-promise http requests to modify the request options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004758/how-can-i-intercept-all-node-request-promise-http-requests-to-modify-the-request)