# How can I intercept all node request-promise http requests to modify the request options?

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I would like to create a **global** request interceptor for `request-promise` based requests so that I can add an `x-request-id` header to all outgoing requests. Since the behaviour is common across all outgoing requests, I prefer to not have to add this functionality everywhere that I am making a request.

I don't notice such functionality in the library documentation.

Comment: you got this done?

Comment: Talk about time on your hands... correcting US English spellings to British spellings?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [request.defaults()](https://github.com/request/request#requestdefaultsoptions)

Comment: I didn't realize I had access to all the normal request methods.  The downside here is that if I am using RP in many modules, I will have to create and provide access to this wrapped instance across all modules.  It's a shame that the RP global instance (static) can't be set (without monkey patching or something).

Comment: You can open an issue in github repo, maybe the contributors and/or you can add your desired functionality. Why not ?!